# How do I trigger ad on button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that shows up an advertisement as the user opens a website. However, I want to make it so that when a user clicks a buton, the ad gets triggered and redirects the user to that website. I also want to make the button to cool down for 3 seconds, then let the user click on it again to go to a different URL.
In short - a user clicks a button. It first executes the ad, then cools down for 3 seconds, then after the second click it executes a .
Here's the :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
        'key' : 'key',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 300,
        'width' : 160,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.variousformatscontent.com/key/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.write`.

Comment: thats the scipt that came by default with the ad placement.

Comment: @Dai incorrect. var/let is not mandatory

Comment: How would you tell the script to load a different ad?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+load+script+button+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.